# Dieharder random test suite does not compile

Tags: c++, random

I am trying to use [dieharder](https://webhome.phy.duke.edu/~rgb/General/dieharder.php) to test quality of a random sequence. In order to compile it on windows, I have installed msys and [gsl](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/) developments. GSL compiled without any problems. To compile Dieharder, I first run `./configure`
and then when I entered `make` in msys, it returns below error messages:

```
(cd libdieharder; \make)
make[1]: Entering directory `/f/dieharder-3.31.1/libdieharder'
/bin/sh ../libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..  -DVERSION=3.31.1 -DLITTLE_ENDIAN=1 -I ../include -I /usr/local/include  -std=c99 -Wall -pedantic -g -O2 -MT libdieharder_la-dab_dct.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libdieharder_la-dab_dct.Tpo -c -o libdieharder_la-dab_dct.lo `test -f 'dab_dct.c' || echo './'`dab_dct.c
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -DVERSION=3.31.1 -DLITTLE_ENDIAN=1 -I ../include -I /usr/local/include -std=c99 -Wall -pedantic -g -O2 -MT libdieharder_la-dab_dct.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libdieharder_la-dab_dct.Tpo -c dab_dct.c  -DDLL_EXPORT -DPIC -o .libs/libdieharder_la-dab_dct.o
make[1]: Leaving directory `/f/dieharder-3.31.1/libdieharder'
```

The error messages are:

```
dab_dct.c: In function 'fDCT2':
dab_dct.c:251:44: error: 'M_PI' undeclared (first use in this function)
      output[i] += (double) input[j] * cos((M_PI / len) * (0.5 + j) * i);
                                            ^~~~
dab_dct.c:251:44: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
dab_dct.c: In function 'iDCT2':
dab_dct.c:274:30: error: 'M_PI' undeclared (first use in this function)
      sum += input[j] * cos(((M_PI * j) / len) * (0.5 + i));
                              ^~~~
dab_dct.c: In function 'evalMostExtreme':
dab_dct.c:289:15: warning: variable 'pos' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
  unsigned int pos = 0;
               ^~~
make[1]: *** [libdieharder_la-dab_dct.lo] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/f/dieharder-3.31.1/libdieharder'
make: *** [libwulf.time] Error 2
```

My question is whether I should declare the M_PI at the beginning of the file or I made a mistake during installation process?

Comment: @KenWhite, Sorry, you are right. I have added the error messages.

Answer (score 0):

Constants are in [math.h](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/math.h.html) and you can find M_PI there.